# Joining multiple(more than 2) Pyspark Dataframes on multiple conditions dynamically

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, reduce, functools

i have 20 of data frames and i want to combine it into single one having all the columns. my data frames is looking like,

```
course_id   course_name
5011    Web Designing
5012    Web Development
5013    Programming



subject_id  subject_name    course_name
221 HTML    5011
222 CSS 5011
223 JavaScript  5011
224 PHP 5012
225 Python  5012
226 .Net    5012
227 Java    5013
228 C++ 5013



chapter_id  chapter_name    subject_id
101 HTML Text   221
102 HTML Image  221
103 HTML List   221
104 HTML Link   221
105 HTML Form   221
106 CSS Border  222
107 CSS Position    222
108 CSS Selector    222
109 PHP conditions  224
110 PHP arrays  224
111 Java Methods    227
```

So i have more than 50 data frames so last columns is changing each time.

So my question is how can i make single resultant dataframe which will look like below,

```
course_name subject_name    chapter_name    subchapter_name
Web Designing   HTML    HTML Text   HTML Heading
Web Designing   HTML    HTML Text   HTML Paragraph
Web Designing   HTML    HTML List   HTML Ordered List
Web Designing   HTML    HTML List   HTML Unordered List
Web Designing   HTML    HTML Link   HTML Image Link
Web Designing   HTML    HTML Link   HTML Text Link
Web Designing   CSS CSS Border  CSS Border Color
Web Designing   CSS CSS Border  CSS Border Style
Web Designing   CSS CSS Border  CSS Border Width
Web Designing   CSS CSS Position    CSS Absolute Position
Web Designing   CSS CSS Selector    CSS Element Selector
Web Development PHP PHP Conditions  PHP Switch Condition
Web Development PHP PHP Conditions  PHP if Condition
Web Development PHP PHP Arrays  PHP Associative array
Web Development PHP PHP Arrays  PHP Index Array
Programming Java    Java Methods    ava Method Overloading
Programming Java    Java Methods    ava Method Parameter
```

Code that i am currently using is below, but as we want to go live with 500 reports we need to do it in Pyspark API.

```
SELECT courses.course_name, 
subjects.subject_name,
chapters.chapter_name, 
subchapters.subchapter_name 
FROM courses
INNER JOIN subjects ON courses.course_id = subjects.course_id
INNER JOIN chapters ON subjects.subject_id = chapters.subject_id
INNER JOIN subchapters ON chapters.chapter_id = subchapters.chapter_id;
```

Any help how it can be done using pyspark API. I have tried this but i wan to change join condition everytime of join

```
def f(dfs):
    df1 = dfs[0]
    for df2 in dfs[1:]:
        df1 = df1.join(df2, ["id"])
    return df1
```

Answer (score 0):

However, you need to explicitly specify the `join` field. The function can then be modified slightly to meet your needs.

```
def f(dfs, join_cols):
    df = df1
    for i in range(len(dfs)):
        df = df.join(dfs[i], join_cols[i])
    return df


df_ls = [df2, df3]
join_ls = ['course_id', 'subject_id']
df = f(df_ls, join_ls)
df.show()
```

Comment: This looks good but the problem is i wanto define condtion of join based on dataframes
like **"df1.A1==df2.B1"**

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this now and it is some how working but don't know if this is the great answer.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').getOrCreate()

lst1 = [[1, 2, 3], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']]
lst2 = [[2, 3, 4], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']]
lst3 = [[1, 2, 4], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']]

R1 = Row("A1", "A2", "A3")
R2 = Row("B1", "B2", "B3")
R3 = Row("C1", "C2", "C3")
df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([R1(*r) for r in zip(*lst1)]).toDF().alias('df1')
df2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([R2(*r) for r in zip(*lst2)]).toDF().alias('df2')
df3 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([R3(*r) for r in zip(*lst3)]).toDF().alias('df3')

list_tup = [(df1, df2, "df1.A1", "df2.B1"),
            (df2, df3, "df2.B1", "df3.C1"),
            (df1, df3, "df1.A1", "df3.C1")]

df_1 = list_tup[0][0]
for x in list_tup:
    df_1 = x[0].join(x[1], on=F.col(x[2]) == F.col(x[3]), how="left_outer")

df_1.show()



+---+---+---+----+----+----+
| A1| A2| A3|  C1|  C2|  C3|
+---+---+---+----+----+----+
|  1|  A| aa|   1|   A|  aa|
|  2|  B| bb|   2|   B|  bb|
|  3|  C| cc|null|null|null|
+---+---+---+----+----+----+
```